# How to trigger a JSP page refresh from server.?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

**Requirement :**

Trigger a jsp page refresh when some value in the server changes.

Ajax is an option, but refreshing the JSP at a particular interval will increase the load on the server. Since i am dealing with a system that handles large amount of data, optimizing with the best having the higher priority.

Any new Technology or design pattern that may help is greatly appreciated.

> **NB :** I have seen the technologies that match my requirement in HTML 5. But i am looking for something that works with everything.

Answer (score 5):

> Any new Technology or design pattern.

Yes, there is a new technology named `WebSocket`. It is bi-directional and full-duplex. That means server can trigger client. You can get support of `Websocket` on Java EE 7 or Spring 4.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 7 Websocket tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm)
- [Spring 4 Websocket tutorial](http://syntx.io/using-websockets-in-java-using-spring-4/)

Comment: @Dileep, That is HTML5 feature. Currently most updated browser support this feature.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the fast reply. But my application is used by idiots all over the world they doesn't even know what is HTML 5. Most of the system runs in XP. I have considered this and reverse ajax etc. But all works on HTML 5. I haven't found a solution that work on prev version of HTML.